# Clarification with JWT implementation in PHP

Tags: php, jwt

I recently heard about JWT and by this I read the docs provided by this [site](https://jwt.io/). My questions are as follows:

1. Is https://jwt.io/ the official site of JWT?
2. Do I need to register on that site in order to use JWT on my application?
3. Can anyone provide a straightforward explanation of how does JWT be implemented, if #2 is no.

Comment: not a PHP guy but, no. No you do not need to register, here's a tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/ (I don't wan't to dumb down how its implement it in a tldr since it could lead to misunderstandings, maybe someone else with a much better understanding could?)

Answer (score 0):

JWT is a standard for creating access token, you can [read more on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)

1. No
2. Surely not
3. In my current application we use JWT with PHP Symfony on server side. 
   We implemented it with the [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle), it's easy to setup, but if you want more flexibility you can build you own service.